# How to check bytes value is int or float?

Tags: c#

Let's assume that bytes contain int or float only.
It's my case.

Is there any way to know the value in bytes is int or float in C#?

The bytes can contain both int format or float format( sign + exponent + fraction ). 
To read data from bytes using 
BitConverter.ToInt32 and BitConverter.ToSingle makes huge difference.

```
byte[]  src = new byte[4];

// float or int assignment to src bytes
// ...
// ...

// way to know the value is int or float?
if(/* src is int format */)
    int valueInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(src, 0);
else 
    float valueFloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(src, 0);
```

Comment: `Is there any way to know the value in bytes is int or float in C#?` No.

Comment: Yes, it would make a difference. It would be different if you assumed it was ISO-8859-1 text, too. Basically you need to know how to interpret the data. They're just bytes.

Comment: You can't. Especially for simple numeric types. Every bit pattern is valid for both

Comment: To put it another way: if someone said that a certain real-life object had a length of 25 could you tell *just from that information* whether they meant feet, inches, meters, centimeters, something else?

Comment: If your values lie within a specific range, you might be able to narrow down whether the pattern is an `int` or `float`, since for the most part equivalent values are not encoded identically. But if all possible valid `int` values and all possible valid `float` values need to be recognized, then no. Note that a `float` can represent every integer from -2^24 through 2^24 exactlly, so if all you need is "small" integers, you can just stick to `float`.

Comment: You can estimate the probability whether this is `int` or `float`. But don't think that 30% `int` vs 60% `float` is something trustworthy. It can be useful if you have to scan array of bytes and have to find potential location of area with `float` or `int` values. But generally it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is there any way to know the value in bytes is int or float in C#?"
Heck No!

Even if you knew that the bytes in memory were a string, you could not read or even define wehre it ends without also knowing wich of the hundreds of possible encodings were used:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

The same bytes can be a valid bitmap or the most dangerous virus of our time, it all depends how they are interpreted (as a bitmap or executeable code). File-endings in windows are used to define how any set of bytes should be interpreted (wich programm it should be handed too). A lot of common formats carry a way to be "identified" as the first binary information.

Carrying type information and other stuff needed for interpretation is usually the reason we transmit stuff via De(Sertialsiation) like XML, JSON, etc.